# Select QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, select, transparency, layer, qgraphicsitem

I have problems selecting my QGraphicsItem.

I have multiple Items (Line and Ellipse) and Itemgroups (containing lines).
In some cases they are overlaying each other but are still visible because of transparency.

For example: I first create a small circle and later i create a bigger circle around the small one.

How can I select the small circle?

I only want an item beeing selected if i click on a visible nontransparent part of it (maybe with some tolerance for lines of 1px width). How can I do that?

A small example how i create a circle:

```
circleToDraw = new QGraphicsEllipseItem;
this->addItem(circleToDraw);
circleToDraw->setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 1, Qt::SolidLine));
circleToDraw->setPos(origPoint);
circleToDraw->setRect(origPoint.y() - event->scenePos().y(), origPoint.y() - event->scenePos().y(), (event->scenePos().y() - origPoint.y())*2, (event->scenePos().y() - origPoint.y())*2);
```

Later i will also implement some QImages with transparent parts. Here the problem will be again, that I want to select Items under the transparent part.

Thank you!

**Edit**

My code for now:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem *> items = this->items(event->scenePos());
for each(QGraphicsItem* item in items)
{
    if(item->opacity() == 1){
    //opacity() does not work as expected
    //circle will still be deleted when I click the (transparent) inside of it
        //item->setSelected(true); //selects all items while pressing mouse, but only top item after releasing mouse. why?
        this->removeItem(item);
        delete(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you could of course override the corresponding mouse event(s) in your scene, get all items at the mouse cursor and try to find out which is painted at that location to determine which needs to be selected. But what happens if the painted area of two items overlap there? Some programs have a functionality, that displays a menu on the cursor of all possible items when you press the mouse for a while, this could also be implemented in the event and a timer for instance.

Comment: I know how to get an item via itemAt(QPointF) but this only gives me the most top item. How can I get all items? And how can I find out whether at this point something is drawn or not? Also itemAt(QPointF) is obsolet, how do I use itemAt(QPointF), QTransform)?

Comment: "how do I use itemAt(QPointF), QTransform)" - To get the scene from an item, you have the `scene()` function. To get the view, you get the `views()` list of the scene... and perhaps take the first. Or you could use a null transform.

Comment: To get all the items at a given position, use the `items()` function on the scene.

Comment: Thank you with items() i am now able to select (and delete) all items at given point. But still they are deleted even when I click at a transparent point. I tried `if(item->opacity() == 1)` but this doesen't seem to work as expected...

Comment: well okay, deleting all items works (despite I do not want all items to delete) but setSelected(true) still selects only the top item (added some code)